# How to simulate a click button with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bootstrap dropdown menu, and I need to set the default option (`Highest positive votes`) when the user reload the page.

I tried it `$('#dropdownMenuButton span.option').text("Highest positive votes");`, but it didn't solve my problem because I can't keep the text on the js file, I need to keep the text on the html file due the translation of the django framework `{% trans 'Highest positive votes' %}`

**HTML Code**

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">        
    <span>{% trans 'Sorted by' %}: </span><span class="option">{% trans 'Highest positive votes' %}</span>
</button>

<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item itemSort" href="#" name='thumbsUp'>{% trans 'Highest positive votes' %}</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item itemSort" href="#" name='thumbsDown'>{% trans 'Highest negative votes' %}</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item itemSort" href="#" name='creationOrder'>{% trans 'Latest' %}</a>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('a.itemSort').click(function() {
    if (this.name == 'thumbsUp') {
        ...
    } else if (this.name == 'thumbsDown') {
        ...
    } else if (this.name == 'creationOrder') {
        ...
    }
    $('#dropdownMenuButton span.option').text($(this).text());
});
```

I expect that when I relaod the page, the dropdown-menu show the text `Highest positive votes`.

I'm trying to simulate the click on the `thumbsUp` option on the `dropdownMenuButton`.

How can I do that? There's a better way to solve it?

ps.: I tried implement the solutions that I read in another questions similar to that. But it's not the same problem.

Comment: How all the anchor tags have same ids?

Comment: I need to call the function in the js file. I tried something like `$("#dropdownMenuButton").on('click', parameter)`. But it  didn't work. You're right, the same id is not correct, I'm gonna fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a few spans inside the button and then hide/show needed one. Just a bit of CSS and JS is required

```js
function show (classname) {
  // targeting your button
  const button = document.getElementById('button')
  // find all possible texts inside of it
  const spans = button.getElementsByTagName('span')
  // hide all of them
  Array.prototype.slice.call(spans).forEach(span => span.classList.remove("visible"))
  // select one to be shown
  const next = button.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0]
  // show it
  next.classList.add('visible')
}
```

```css
.thumbsUp,
.thumbsDown {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">
  <span class="thumbsUp visible">Thumbs UP</span>
  <span class="thumbsDown">Thumbs Down</span>
</button>
<div>
  <button onclick="show('thumbsUp')">Show thumbs up</button>
  <button onclick="show('thumbsDown')">Show thumbs down</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't code exactly how u said, but I used your idea to solve it. Tku

Answer (score 1):

To click a specific anchor, you can target it with a property selector, like this.

```
$('a.itemSort[name="thumbsUp]"').click()
```

Comment: Add quotes in name selector `$('a.itemSort[name="thumbsUp"]').click();`

Comment: Nice catch @Shubham. For strings of alphanumeric value only it works, but other special character may wreck havoc...

Comment: It's not working. I need to simulate a click on `a.itemSort`, because I will call it in other js function

Answer (score 1):

django template variables only run at runtime when the page first loads and when you click on the menu it does not take the translated text by django 'trans' formatter.

so you can solve your problem by saving the dropdown items text in javascript object variable and use it like that:

```
var translatedTextsObj = {
    'thumbsUp': {% trans "Highest positive votes" %},
    'thumbsDown': {% trans "Highest negative votes" %},
    'creationOrder': {% trans "Latest" %}
}

$('a.itemSort').click(function () {

   if(this.name == 'thumbsUp'){
       ...
   }

   else if(this.name == 'thumbsDown'){
       ...
   }

   else if(this.name=='creationOrder'){
       ...
   }

   $('#dropdownMenuButton span.option').text(translatedTextsObj[this.name]); // here is the translated text
});
```

Comment: I got it: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. When I use double quotes: ` 'thumbsUp': '{% trans "Highest positive votes" %}' ` it doesn't translate.

Comment: I just removed the single string quotes from django formatter, can you please try it now

Comment: Applying those modifications. I got it `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %`

Comment: please be aware that in order of this to work, the javascript code should be inside the html page and that html page should be connect to django engine somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#dropdownMenuButton').html("<span>{% trans 'Sorted by' %}: </span><span class="option">{% trans 'Highest positive votes' %}</span>");
```